# Excel VBA - If row value copy other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hei,

I need help with Excel. For better undrestanding, picture is attached.
Basically i need excel to go through row by row and copy all rows with set values (see picture).

- **Logic:**
- If col1 value "1" copy (always)´
- incase col3 value "X" copy also row below (value=2)
- If col3 not "X" copy and skip to next col1 = 2
- If col3 not "X" copy and skip to next col1 = 1
- If col1 value "1" copy (always)
- incase col3 value not "X" skip to next col1=1

etc.

**EDIT:[ATTACHED EXCEL FILE WITH EXAMPLE OUTPUT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/chdag9xeupbc4nd/Example.xlsm?dl=0)**

[Excel - Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA2tV.jpg)

```
If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
    //*copy entire row and skip everything until Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1*//
    else if Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 And Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = "x" Then
    *copy entire row and continue loop*

    If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 Then
    //*copy entire row and skip everything until Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 or higer*//
    else if Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 And Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = "x" Then
    *copy entire row and continue loop*

    If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 3 Then
    //*copy entire row and skip everything until Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 3 or higher*//
    else if Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 3 And Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = "x" Then
    *copy entire row and continue loop*


    If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 4 Then
    //*copy entire row and skip everything until Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 4 or higher*//
    else if Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 4 And Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = "x" Then
    *copy entire row and continue loop*
```

Comment: not too clear for me. add what you coded so far to help us help you

Comment: Thank you for the comment, im not good at coding. If i copy my code, it would confuse more. Instead i attached example excel file with needed output.

Comment: the attached screenshot isn't useful for me to understand. I could help if you add more detail. for instance add screenshot of the "before" and "after" scenarios

Comment: Thank you for quick replay. I attached excel file into post. There is before and after example.

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to the code, now it copies data from columns A:E, to add more columns change where it says "5" in Cells(i + 1, 5) or Cells(counter_rows, 5) and add a different column number.

The rows with data are stored in an array to speed up the code and make it more compact.

Also you should put this subroutine in a MODULE in VBA. Don't add code to Sheets.

```
Sub copy_rows_to_sheet2()
Dim nb_rows As Integer
Dim counter_rows As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'speed up code
nb_rows = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'count the number of rows with data on sheet(1)

counter_rows = 2 'the first row on sheet(2) where we start copying data from


Dim Arr() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array, stores data from range on the sheets (any number of rows and columns)

For i = 2 To nb_rows
      Sheets(1).Select  'to add data to array, first select the sheet1
        If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Or Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 Then
            If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = "x" Then  'we copy 2 rows when we have x in col 3
             Arr = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 1, 5)).Value  'copy all values from row i and next row counter_rows and columns (A to E=5)
             Sheets(2).Select  'before the array is pasted to sheet2 first it needs to be selected
             Range(Cells(counter_rows, 1), Cells(counter_rows + 1, 5)).Value = Arr
               counter_rows = counter_rows + 2 'counter increments by 2 rows
            Else

              Arr = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Value  'copy row i and 5 columns
              Sheets(2).Select
              Range(Cells(counter_rows, 1), Cells(counter_rows, 5)).Value = Arr
                  counter_rows = counter_rows + 1 'counter increments by 1 row
            End If
        End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn back

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this script works, but i need more information to be copied. I attached new example file, so you would better undrestand what is ouput and criterias.

Comment: Thank you. It is really close to my output, but i need little more complex information from the query. I added code example, based on your code.